# How to implement back/PopUpTo when clicking the bottom navigation bar using setupWithNavController in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I used setupWithNavController to handle mutiple back stack navigation in Kotlin. I want to get back to the one of the navigation page item if the bottom nav bar is clicked. For example, there are 3 tabs, which are home, notication, and setting. In setting page, there are profile page, about page, etc. Let say i clicked the profile page and then navigate to other to page to edit name. Then, i want to get back to setting page by clciking the bottom nav bar setting icon

How i can navigate back to setting page if I decided to click the setting bottom nav bar since if i click the setting bottom nav bar, i still in edit name page and cant go back to setting page. I want to make if the nav bar got clicked, i can back to setting page